# ElasticSearch query from list to contain X and contain something other than X

Tags: python, elasticsearch, filter

Suppose within my Elasticsearch I have a field 'ListNames' that provides a list of dictionaries. One of the keys within each dictionary is 'People'. My goal is to Query/Filter from ES all relevant profiles where 'ListNames.People' contains 'Adam' and contains a name that is NOT 'Adam'. Without a verbose list of all possible Names (since there are many), how could I achieve this? Thank you for any help in advance.

The below Code shows examples of post's I have tried

```
#Note: this returns profiles with ONLY Adam contained in the ListNames.
post_data = {
    "size": 30,
    "query": {
        'match':{
            'ListNames.People':'Adam'
        }
    }
}



#################
post_data = {
    "size": 30,
    "query": {
        'bool': {
            'should': [{
                'match': {
                    'ListNames.People': 'Adam'
                }
            }],
            'must_not':[
                {'match':{'ListNames.People':'Adam'}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
###################
post_data = {
    "size": 30,
    "query": {
        'bool': {
            'must': [{
                'match': {
                    'ListNames.People': 'Adam'
                }
            }],
            'must_not':[
                {'match':{'ListNames.People':'Adam'}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The first post returns results only containing Adam, which is not desired, and the other two return empty.

Answer (score 0):

**Update after discussion in comments**

You have to use painless to check such condition. Please note that using script can have performance degradation.

The query will be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "ListNames.People": "Adam"
          }
        },
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": "for(int i = 0; i < doc['ListNames.People'].length; i++) { if(doc['ListNames.People'][i] != params.person) { return true; }} return false;",
              "lang": "painless",
              "params": {
                "person": "Adam"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not precisely, I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I am looking for documents which contain at least two entries in ListNames, where at least 1 of them is Adam, and at least 1 of them is Not Adam

Comment: What if there are 3 entries, 2 with Adam and 1 not Adam? Is it like this that there should be one with Adam and not all are Adam?

Comment: In that case, I would want to match that document. I.e. Any document that contains at least 1 entry as 'Adam' and 1 entry that is anything (non-null) other than 'Adam', I would like to match. The number of 'Adam' or non 'Adam' does not matter beyond that